# Trying to interpret a postfix notation to a mathematical phrase

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, stack

I'm using Java and in my application i have to transform a Binary expression tree into a mathematical phrase (with terminals, operators and parentheses).

The first part was transforming the tree to a postfix notation and i did it successfully, but the second part (postfix to math phrase) is causing me troubles.

Here is the code:

```
public static String postfixInterpret(String postfix) {
    Stack<Character> stack = toStack(postfix);
    Stack<String> expression_stack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<String> temp_stack = new Stack<>();

    System.out.println(postfix);
    while (!stack.empty()) {
        if (Tree.getTERMINALS().indexOf(stack.peek()) > -1) {
            expression_stack.push(stack.pop().toString());
        }
        else {

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (!expression_stack.empty()) {
                    temp_stack.push(expression_stack.pop());
                } else {
                    temp_stack.push("Null");
                }
            }
            String expression_create = "(" + temp_stack.pop() + " " + stack.pop() + " " + temp_stack.pop() + ")";

            expression_stack.push(expression_create);
        }
    }

    return expression_stack.pop();
}
```

The part inside the `else` with the `for` loop is to make sure a sub-tree with only one child will still become a logical phrase, so as a **+** node with **A** and **B** child nodes will result with **"A+B"** i want a **+** node with only **A** child will result with the phrase **"A+Null"**.

I debugged it and found that when i have a part in my prefix notation with only one terminal and an operator after it, and the `expression_stack` already has something in it, the phrase is not true.

---

**For example:**

This tree:

[image: Tree]

Gives me `"BH|%GI*|^E+AF++|%"` using the simple recursive "tree to postfix" function i made, which is right.

But instead of: `((((B|H) % Null) ^ ((G*I) | Null)) % (Null | ((Null + E) + (A + F))))`

I get: `(Null % (Null | (((Null ^ ((Null % (B | H)) | (G * I))) + E) + (A + F))))`

I tried debugging slowly but i can't find a way to fix this issue. What is the problem with my function?

Comment: So, since you are using Java, why the C++ tag?  The two are different languages.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i just noticed it was edited out, an honest mistake, probably pressed it in the automatic tag suggestions, sorry.

Comment: It's just as easy to convert tree->infix as it is to convert postfix->infix. Is there a particular reason you want to convert to postfix first?

Comment: @immibis i also have an infix notation function but i figured the parentheses addition would be easier with the postfix notation. My goal is to add parentheses and 'Null' if an operator had only one operand.

Comment: How is your function supposed to know whether `AB|&` means `((A | B) & Null)` or `(A & (B | Null))`? You need to include the Nulls in the postfix notation to make it unambiguous.

Comment: @immibis for now that's what i did, i changed my "tree to postfix" function to check if an operator has only one child and adds '0', but i would still really want to know if there's a way to achieve my goal of doing it with a regular postfix notation and the information all the operators must have 2 operands.

Comment: @argamanza But some of your operators *don't* have 2 operands.